# Explanation of MPI communicator types

Tags: networking, mpi, hpc

I have an application where I want to split the communicator. I was looking at the MPI documentation for [MPI_Comm_split_type](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.1/man3/MPI_Comm_split_type.3.php), and it has the option to split on the cluster and computational unit(CU). Can someone explain what defines a CU and cluster in this case. I doubt the cluster is the whole network, as that would just be COMM World and think it some reference how the network topology is laid out.

I tried to find some reference to this, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything `OMPI_COMM_TYPE` is an OpenMPI extension on the standard. So you won't find much documentation. The exact meaning may even by implementation dependent.

Note that MPI 4 has more split types, but OpenMPI 4 does not have the 4 standard yet.

Also: split type "cluster" refers to the case where you hook up multiple clusters into a really large comm world. I have no idea what `CU` is. Likely implementation dependent.

Comment: The extra split types featured by Open MPI basically maps to `hwloc` types. you can use them if you want to have on communicator per L3 cache/ socket / core / ...